# ReduxForm decorator, no-class-assign error after ejecting create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, redux, decorator, react-redux, redux-form

I recently ejected my create-react-app and I'm receiving an error with ReduxForm that's preventing webpack compilation. Here's the error: "error  'NewComplaintModal' is a class  no-class-assign". It appears to be associated with the redux form decorator at the bottom, but I can't find any other implementations in the redux-form docs. Any idea how to fix this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as Actions from '../actions';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import DatePicker from "react-bootstrap-date-picker";

class NewComplaintModal extends Component {
  close() {
    this.props.actions.hideModal();
  }

  handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
    this.props.actions.submitComplaint(formProps);
  }

  render(){
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    const show = this.props.modalType ? true : false;

    const RenderDatePicker = ({input, meta: {touched, error} }) => (
      <div>
        <DatePicker showClearButton={false} {...input} />
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    );

    return(
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}

NewComplaintModal = reduxForm({
  form: 'newComplaintModal'
})(NewComplaintModal);


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    modal: state.modal
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewComplaintModal)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you're declaring a class called `NewComplaintModal` like this

```
class NewComplaintModal extends Component {
  ...
}
```

Then, you're treating your `NewComplaintModal`, which is a class declaration, like it's a variable, like this:

```
NewComplaintModal = reduxForm({
  form: 'newComplaintModal'
})(NewComplaintModal);
```

This is why you're seeing the specific error, that is complaining about a class being reassigned. To fix this, I would recommend skipping the middle step of using the `reduxForm` decorator before `connect` and just chaining them using the decorator syntax:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as Actions from '../actions';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import DatePicker from "react-bootstrap-date-picker";

export class NewComplaintModal extends Component {
  close() {
    this.props.actions.hideModal();
  }

  handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
    this.props.actions.submitComplaint(formProps);
  }

  render(){
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    const show = this.props.modalType ? true : false;

    const RenderDatePicker = ({input, meta: {touched, error} }) => (
      <div>
        <DatePicker showClearButton={false} {...input} />
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    );

    return(
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    modal: state.modal
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
  };
}


// use decorators around an extension of your component
// to plug into redux and redux-form
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
@reduxForm({ form: 'newComplaintModal' })
export default class NewComplaintModalContainer extends NewComplaintModal {}
```

If you don't want to use the decorator syntax, you can do something like this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  reduxForm({ form: 'newComplaintModal' })(
    NewComplaintModal
  )
)
```

This approach essentially insulates your component from the configuration-like elements, namely anything related to interacting with the application state.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

@jakee pointed why you are getting the error.

Another way you can do is to use the `compose` method of redux.

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
...
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  reduxForm({...}),
)(NewComplaintModal);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a less-than elegant solution: Instead of an uninitialized NewComplaintModal, declare a new variable with a different name and pass that variable to the return value of the connect function.

For example:

```
const NewComplaintModalTemp = reduxForm({
  form: 'newComplaintModal'
})(NewComplaintModal);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewComplaintModalTemp)
```

If anyone has a better solution or wants to share any other relevant info to help explain why this is necessary that would be greatly appreciated.